# Php rabbitmq listener отправить echo в браузер

Tags: php, rabbitmq

```
    public function actionCallback(): void
    {
        $this->setHeaders();

        self::listener();
    }

    private function setHeaders(): void
    {
        set_time_limit(0);
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Connection: keep-alive');
        header('Cache-Control: no-store');
        echo 'retry: 10000' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function listener($timeout = 0): void
    {
        try {
            $context = self::getAmqpConnection();
            $queue = $context->createQueue('queue');

            $subscriptionConsumer = $context->createSubscriptionConsumer();
            $subscriptionConsumer->subscribe(
                $context->createConsumer($queue),
                function (PsrMessage $message, PsrConsumer $consumer) {
                    try {
                        $msg = json_decode($message->getBody());
                        // сюда заходит
                        $id = time();
                        $msg = json_encode($msg, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
                        self::sendMsg($id, $msg);

                        $consumer->acknowledge($message);
                    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
                    }
                }
            );
            $subscriptionConsumer->consume($timeout);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        }
    }

    private static function sendMsg(string $id, string $msg): void
    {
        echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
```

Хочу реализовать server sent events на php - https://bigboxcode.com/php-server-sent-events-sse

Но при запуске слушателя очереди оно просто в бесконечном цикле и не отдает результат

Возможно ли из closure subscribe вывести echo?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SSE является стандартом, который описывает способы начала передачи данных клиентам с момента организации клиентом первого соединения.***

А AMQP это ***ассинхронный*** протокол, т.е. представьте, что вы запускаете свою callback-функцию совершенно в другом процессе, который теряет ваше "первое" подключение, которое как раз необходимо для отправки событий на клиент.

**Через AMQP шину - так сделать не получится.**

Comment: через редис паб\саб ситуация идентична? https://bigboxcode.com/php-server-sent-events-sse пробовал их пример - такое же зависание как и в случае с ребит

Comment: @des1roer нет, с pub/sub ситуация иная, если посмотрите на пример, то увидите, что там уже никаких callback-ов нет, т.е. вы устанавливаете соединение с клиентом и держите его, т.к. находитесь в том же скрипте, в таком случае, все будет работать. Как уже писал, при работе с amqp шиной, понимайте callback как отдельный процесс, который с родительским ничего общего не имеет.